# Recalling information from dictionaries within dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

So say I have a number of dictionaries within a dictionary

```
d = {'a': {'name': bob, 'class': 2a}, 'b': {'name': mike, 'class': 2b}, 'c': {'name': ben, 'class': 2b}}
```

How would I go about identifying items within each of these internal dictionaries. Say I wanted to identify the keys of the internal dictionaries that were in 'class' '2b'. How would I code this so that it gave me the keys 'b' and 'c'???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries are meant to do lookups only via their keys.  That's not to say this can't be done, but if you need arbitrary lookups you'd be better served by using a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the keys of your dictionary and check each sub-`dict`.

```
[k for k in d if d[k]['class'] == '2b']
Out[16]: ['c', 'b']
```

optionally,

```
[k for k,v in d.items() if v['class'] == '2b']
Out[17]: ['c', 'b']
```